# How to set an IPN URL for PayPal Recurring Payments using NVP Method(CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile)?

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions, notify, recurring, paypal-nvp

1. In CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API Operation (NVP) no options for set IPN URL
2. How to track subscription?
3. NVP API CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile operation Support **NOTIFYURL field**?

On PayPal provide some information

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/#id089EG030E5Z

Answer (score 2):

You can't configure IPN Url in CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile operation, you have to configure it in the business account you use.

In the account configuration there is an IPN section.